# Display a many-to-many relation in admin without need to edit children

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

My model is:

```
class CustomerAccount(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    customer_account = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerAccount, related_name='users', blank=True)
    default_customer_account = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAccount, related_name='users_using_default_account', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to display in the admin interface of the CustomerAccount this sort of thing:
[image]

I don't need to add a MyUser in the CustomerAccount interface.

Most SO questions and docs are related to show an Inline class in the admin, but I don't need it.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The functinality shown above you get by making adding the desired field to the filter_horizontal list ([docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)).

Comment: No, the docs is the other way around: filter_horizontal would be in the MyUser admin, I want it to the CustomerAccount admin. And I can't change the model.

Comment: You want to add it the other way round? You mean you cannot change the model at all - can you explecitely handle the manytomany field?